# Django Static File handling error

Tags: python, django, static

I am having an error while handling static files in django. Whenever I load the webpage the images don't load in

the .html file

```
{%for i in all_memes%}
    <div class="memes">
        {%load static%}
        <a href="{%url 'meme_detail' i.id%}"><img style="width:150px;height:150px;" src="{%static  '/photos/static/uploaded_files/{{i.photo_link}}' %}" /></a>

    </div>

    {%endfor%}
```

the urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns=[
#all my urls
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'photos/static')
STATIC_ROOT="/photos/static/uploaded_files"
```

the tree structure for my **app** looks like ->

```
photos
├── admin.py
├── admin.pyc
├── apps.py
├── apps.pyc
├── forms.py
├── forms.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── models.py
├── models.pyc
├── static
│   └── uploaded_files
│       ├── 1489928056_6771295_Screenshot_from_2017-03-19_17-58-27.png
│       └── 1489928993_8345437_Screenshot_from_2017-03-19_17-58-27.png
├── templates
│   └── photos
│       ├── add.html
│       ├── detail.html
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── invalid.html
│       ├── login.html
│       └── meme.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
├── urls.pyc
├── views.py
└── views.pyc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html file use this tag {% load staticfiles %} 
your code should be like this :-

```
{%for i in all_memes%}
<div class="memes">
    {%load static%}
    <a href="{%url 'meme_detail' i.id%}"><img style="width:150px;height:150px;" src="{%static  '/photos/static/uploaded_files/{{i.photo_link}}' %}" /></a>

</div>

{%endfor%}
```

Comment: thank you  
PS.You dont have {%load staticfiles%} in your code

Comment: Although this would work on your current system but it would fail on any other as soon as the parent directory structure or path of the static files changes!! You should never use full path in the static block! There is a reason why you keep the `STATIC_ROOT` in the `settings.py` configurable, so that you can change it as per the environment, else you will have to change ALL your templates.

Comment: also you should use STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/photos/static/uploaded_files') , never hardcode your path directory, use relative paths

Answer (score 0):

You should give relative paths in the `static` block.

```
{% static 'img_relative_path' %}
{% static i.photo_link %}
```

Basically, since you have already declared the **root** folder for static files, you need to give paths that are *relative* to this path.

e.g.

```
Complete path - /photos/static/images/random.jpg
Static root   - /photos/static
Relative path - images/random.jpg
```

Also, you don't need to use `{{i.photo_link}}` inside the `{% static ... %}` block, since you can directly use `i.photo_link`, i.e. `{% static i.photo_link %}`.

Comment: what do you mean. I am a noob at this

Comment: Updated my answer, kindly check.

Comment: hey I did what your answer told me to do and now I have a 
AttributeError at /photos/memes-
'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'replace

Comment: Then that is a different question in itself I suppose. But most likely, check what the error says, you must be doing a `str.replace` on the `FieldFile` object instead of one of it's attributes.